# Ошибка spring security на wildfly

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, wildfly

При логине в приложение на spring-security выдает следующее сообщение:

```
{"timestamp":1464679377206,"status":999,"error":"None","message":"No message available"}
```

и редиректит на error-page в приложении развернутом на wildfly, при запуске spring-boot такой проблемы нет. При чем, если затем вбить правильный адрес руками все работает корректно.
Класс запуска приложения:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;

}
```

Thymeleaf форма логина

```
        <div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()" id="anonymous-navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="login">Log in</button>
        </form>
```

Security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userServiceImpl")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/signup", "/add_person").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/images/**");
    }
}
```

**UPD:** 
debug
FirewalledRequest[ HttpServletRequestImpl [ GET /PersonalFinance/error ]]
Похоже на какую-то ошибку фаервола, хотя не уверен, что это рут кос. Как отключить фаервол на debian?

Логи смотрел — там ничего.

[image: debug]

Нашел пару вопросов по этой теме на eng.so:

- [Spring Security with basic auth redirecting to /error for invalid credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954292/spring-security-with-basic-auth-redirecting-to-error-for-invalid-credentials)
- [Spring Security - Remember Me Authentication Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272157/spring-security-remember-me-authentication-error)

Но ни один из представленных там ответов не решил проблему.

Comment: Дебаг смотреть пробовали? Эксепшн какой-нибудь выбрасывает?

Comment: Подебажил немного, но я даже не знаю, куда подкопаться, в приведенных в вопросе классах никаких эксепшенов

Comment: [Вот класс](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/DefaultErrorAttributes.java), который обрабатывает ваше исключение. Данных вы привели мало, так что причину трудно назвать. Очень много чего может быть. Например, может у вас embedded tomcat в classpath завалялся. Повторюсь, смотрите логи в режиме DEBUG, найдите строку на которой вас выбрасывает на это сообщение, и смотрите что ему предшествует.

Comment: embedded tomcat исключаю таким образом  `<dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка появлялась из-за того, что папка с картинками не была включена в проект, но была прописана в spring-security конфигурации. Соответственно, эту папку спринг не находил и ругался.